# how to login with ajax

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter

I am quite new to JS and AJAX and I am having a hard time understanding what the other person has implemented and how I can get it to function properly.

This is my login CI code that is working perfectly, but now I want to do it with AJAX:

```
class Login extends Admin_Controller {
    public function index() {
        if ($this->session->userdata('user')) {
            return redirect('admin/dashboard');
        }
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('txtemail', 'Email', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('txtpassword', 'Password', 'required');
        if ($this->form_validation->run() == TRUE) {
            $username = $this->input->post('txtemail');
            $password = $this->input->post('txtpassword');
            $query = $this->database_model->GetRecord('cms_users', false, array('EmailAddress' => $username, 'Password' => $password));
            if ($query == false) {
                $this->session->set_flashdata('display_msg', 'Invalid Username/Password.');
                return redirect('admin/login');
            } else {
                $this->session->set_userdata('user', $query);
                return redirect('admin/dashboard');
            }
        } else {
            $this->load_view('admin/login');
        }
    }
}
```

And this is my JS:

```
var options = {
    success: function() {
        window.location = 'admin/master_templete';
    },
    error: function() {
        alert('Thanks for error comment!');
    }
};
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#form_login').validate({
        errorElement: 'span',
        errorClass: 'error',
        focusInvalid: false,
        ignore: "",
        rules: {
            email: {
                required: true,
                email: true
            },
            password: {
                required: true
            }
        },
        messages: {
            email: 'Please enter email address',
            password: 'Please enter password'
        },
        errorPlacement: function (error, element) { // render error placement for each input type
            error.insertAfter(element.next());
        },
        submitHandler: function (form,status) {
            $('#form_login').ajaxSubmit(options);
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of redirecting for successful response `return redirect('admin/dashboard');` you should send JSON success message and on client-side you should check if you have received a success msg and then redirect to 'admin/dashboard'

Comment: How ?
as you know i am new

Answer (score 0):

instead of `return redirect('admin/dashboard');`

you should do this:

```
 // If user not found
 return $this->output
        ->set_content_type('application/json')
        ->set_status_header(409)
        ->set_output(json_encode(array(
                'msg' => 'failed'
        )));

 // If user found
 return $this->output
        ->set_content_type('application/json')
        ->set_status_header(200)
        ->set_output(json_encode(array(
                'msg' => 'success'
        )));
```

and in client-side:

```
var options = {
    success:    function(data) {
        if(data.msg == 'success') {
            window.location = 'admin/dashboard';
        } else {
            alert('Invalid User');
        }
    },
    error:    function() {
        alert('Thanks for error comment!');
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

A code snippet that I could think of in AJAX:

```
$ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "ajax/login.php",
data: 'action=login&username='+<?php echo $username;?>+
'&password='+<?php echo $password;?>,
success: alert("You have logged in successfully");
});
```

For the PHP part, you create a login.php file and do the validation
and redirect to the 'admin/dashboard'

Hope this helps you out ! :)

Comment: should i post this code to submitHandler function ?

Comment: yes, you can put it there or you can put it in the file where you're gonna be using it such as login.php

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of ajax that you could use.

```
$(function() {
"use strict";
$("#form_login").submit(function() {
    var data = $("#form_login").serialize(); //this adds up your password and email.
    //alert(data); return false;
    $.ajax({
        url: "/Admin_Controller/index",
        data: data,
        type: "POST",
        success: function(msg) {
            if (msg) {
                $("#display").html(msg); //you really dont need this for a login
            } else {
                $("#display").text("nothing came back For some reason");
            }
        }
    });
    return false;
});
});
```

You are not checking the log in credentials for injection or any other security methods. You need to use an array like this

```
$array = [
   'txtemail'   => html_escape(trim($this->input->post('txtemail'))),
   'txtpassword' => html_escape(trim($this->input->post('txtpassword'))),
];
```

Then do your validation.

Do not use return redirect, just use redirect